# How to store the values retrieved from content script into textboxes with a button click

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I am new to building chrome extension. I am using content script to retrieve the values. But Iam unable to load the values into the popup.html.

Below is the code.

**popup.html**

```
          <head>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="addbookmark">
            <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="url">Url</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url" size="50" value="" /></p
            <p><label for="jsonName">Json Name</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="jsonName" name="jsonName" value=""/></p>
            <p><label for="jsonKey">Key</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="jsonKey" name="jsonKey" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="jsonValue">JSON Value</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="jsonValue" name="jsonValue" value="" /></p>
            <p>
                <input id="submitJson" type="submit" value="Send JSON Object / Valued" />
                <!-- <span id="status-display"></span> -->
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function onPageDetailsReceived(pageDetails)  {
    document.getElementById('title').value = pageDetails.title;
    document.getElementById('url').value = pageDetails.url;
    document.getElementById('jsonValue').value = pageDetails.retrievedJsonValue;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {      
  document.getElementById('submitJson').addEventListener('click',function(){
      var jsonName = document.getElementById('jsonName').value;
      if(jsonName.length > 1){
        var jsonKey = document.getElementById('jsonKey').value;
        var jsonValueToFind = "";
        jsonValueToFind = jsonName+"."+jsonKey;
        chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(eventPage) {              
            eventPage.getPageDetails(function(response){
                alert(response.url);
                document.getElementById('url').value = response.url;
            }, jsonValueToFind);                
        });
      }
  });
});
```

**event.js**

```
function getPageDetails(callback,jsonValueToFind) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                                {code:'var jsonValue ='+jsonValueToFind},
                                function(){
                                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file: 'content.js' });
                                }); 


    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message)  { 
        callback(message); 
    }); 
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    'title': document.title,
    'url': window.location.href,
    'retrievedJsonValue': jsonValue
});
```

Can anybody help me in storing the values to text boxes in the popup boxes, after the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the particular task the event page and separate content script file aren't even necessary:

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"]
```

popup.html:

```html
        ...............
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js ("load" event isn't needed since the script is executed after DOM is parsed):

```
document.getElementById('submitJson').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var jsonName = document.getElementById('jsonName').value;
    if(jsonName.length > 1) {
        var jsonKey = document.getElementById('jsonKey').value;
        getPageDetails(jsonName + "." + jsonKey, function(pageDetails) {
            Object.keys(pageDetails).forEach(function(id) {
                document.getElementById(id).value = pageDetails[id];
            });
        });
    }
});

function getPageDetails(jsonValueToFind, callback) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: jsonValueToFind}, function(result) {
        var value = result[0];
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
            callback({
                url: tabs[0].url,
                title: tabs[0].title,
                jsonValue: value
            });
        });
    }); 
}
```

- `tabId` (the first parameter of executeScript) is simply omitted due to being optional.
- injected script result is the last value in the code and it's passed in an **array** `result`.

Comment: Hi, that working fine. Now If I want to retreive some, json value in window object, like window.configData.ensightenTag.pageSource, its showing, " Cannot read property 'ensightenTag' of undefined. But when I was doing the same in console of developer tools, I am getting the json value. Can you suggest some idea to retrieve the json object from window.configData.ensightenTag

Comment: It's probably an object, so try `code: "JSON.stringify("+jsonValueToFind+")"`

Comment: Still, the same error. woxx.. is there any other way to get the value of window.configData.ensightenTag.pageSource

Comment: That's a separate issue, search for `unsafeWindow chrome` solutions.