# How to get session data for a specific page via chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have a jsp page that holds session data like this,

```html
<input type="hidden" id="sessionData" value="${login}"/>
```

Now, I have a chrome extension and inside the js file (e.g., "popup.js") I want to access the data using `getElementById`.  For example,

```js
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    //alert(tab.id);
    var sessionData = document.getElementById('sessionData').value;
    console.log('session data is '+sessionData);
    alert(sessionData.lang);
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't fetch any session data. No alert is showing. Before fetching session data, `alert(tab.id);` shows the tab id correctly.  (Please don't suggest that `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is deprecated; I already know that.)

Comment: Just to make sure it's said. That is a **horrible, horrible** way of keeping a session. There's absolutely **nothing** stopping the user from changing their dom  so that `<input type="hidden" id="sessionData" value="admin">`.

Comment: this is not for production env, rather for during developing purpose. @MadaraUchiha

Comment: An example with code: [How to store the values retrieved from content script into textboxes with a button click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32166124) For more examples simply google `stackoverflow chrome extension access web page from popup`. Make sure to read the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)

Comment: BTW, the deprecated api tells you how to do it without the deprecation: `chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tab){});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [chrome.tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to execute code in a tab like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

**content_script.js**:

```
var sessionData = document.getElementById('sessionData').value;
console.log('session data is '+sessionData);
alert(sessionData.lang);
```

**NOTE** : You need `activeTab` permissions to execute code in an active tab

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab"
]
```